# What is the meaning of "3" in ID3 algorithm

Tags: machine-learning

I am working on a research paper which deals with ID3 algorithm.
I want to know the meaning of '3' in ID3 algorithm. Is it a version number or something?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is it could have been intentional wordplay or someone did a typo on tree=three which became 3.

Iterative Dichotomizer Tree = Iterative Dichotomizer Three = Iterative Dichotomizer 3

Answer (score 1):

Well, that is a good question. There doesn't seem to be a definite answer. The ID stands for *Iterative Dichotomizer*, what the *3* stands for is unknown.

In his book *Induction of decision trees* by J.R. Quinlan from 1985, so not the paper in which he first published the algorithm, I haven't found access to that one, he says:

> ID3 (Quinlan, 1979, 1983a) is one of a series of programs developed
> from CLS in response to a challenging induction task posed by Donald
> Michie ..

(CLS is the predecessor of ID3)

You can check it [here](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF00116251.pdf) on page 84:

So I guess you're right. It's probably some sort of version number. Although we can't be sure.